# Unit tests for optional units

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a Node.js software that contains several optional units. Each optional unit requires the user to download and install a certain third-party software. The other (non-optional) units work without the third-parties.

Now, I have a set of Mocha.js unit-tests for all units, including the optional units. All tests pass on my computer, since I have all the third-parties installed. However, if a naive user downloads my software package and runs the tests, he will get ugly error messages because of the missing third-parties.

What is the best way to arrange the tests, such that for each user, only the relevant tests will run?

Currently, I use code similar to this:

```
try {
    var thirdparty = require('thirdparty');
    var isTestRelevant = true;
} catch (e) {
    console.warn("WARNING: no thirdparty module - can't run this unitest");
    var isTestRelevant = false;
}

if (isTestRelevant) {
    describe('the unit', function() {
        it('does something', function() { ... }
    });

    describe('the unit', function() {
        it('does something else', function() { ... }
    });
}
```

Is there a better, more general solution for optional units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ideally**, one would use `skip` on `describe` or on `it` to mark a test as pending.  See ["Inclusive tests"](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#inclusive-tests).

Although in the case of your example, a boolean is used to determine whether to mark a test as pending, so here is a solution.

If `it()` has no second argument (the callback function to make assertions in), Mocha appears to mark that test as "pending" (doesn't run the test).  See ["Pending tests"](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#pending-tests).

---

Here is an example.  If we have a file called `conditionalTests.test.js`:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe("The Assert module", function () {
  it("sees true as true", function() {
    assert.ok(true);
  });

  it("sees false as not true", function() {
    assert.ok(!false);
  });
});
```

...and Mocha is called on it, both tests will be run (they pass, not surprisingly):

```
$ mocha --reporter spec conditionalTests.test.js 


  The Assert module
    ✓ sees true as true 
    ✓ sees false as not true 


  2 passing (19ms)
```

...but, if the second test is changed like so (using the `isTestRelevant` variable in a ternary, where `null` is possible as the callback argument):

```
  it("sees false as not true", isTestRelevant ? function() {
    assert.ok(!false);
  } : null);
```

...then that test would show as pending if `isTestRelevant` is false:

```
  The Assert module
    ✓ sees true as true 
    - sees false as not true


  1 passing (19ms)
  1 pending
```

---

To change the test name based on `isTestRelevant`, use the ternary operator again in a similar fashion.

Create another variable to hold the name to change to:

```
var skippedTestName = "A test was skipped because ...";
```

...then change the syntax of that "sees false as not true" test to:

```
  it(
    isTestRelevant ?
      "sees false as not true" : skippedTestName,
    isTestRelevant ?
      function() {
        assert.ok(!false);
      } : null
  );
```

Now the test output will look like:

```
  The Assert module
    ✓ sees true as true 
    - A test was skipped because ...


  1 passing (19ms)
  1 pending
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much better than my previous solution. Is there any way I can make Mocha add a custom message, inside the report, when the test is disabled, for example: "- sees false as not true **this test is disabled because you didn't install the false.js module**"?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi You're welcome.  That is possible, although it makes the situation even messier. :)  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer should be a standard feature of Mocha.js :)

Comment: @tstanton, thanks for this! I've taken a slightly different approach which to create the concept of an optional test. If it passes then all is good, if it fails it marks the particular test as optional. More about it here: https://gist.github.com/dmarcelino/e6b4a0b6d814e3fc906f

Comment: Couldn't resist myself, created a npm module for that gist: https://github.com/dmarcelino/it-optional